# T-SQL: How to get all records prior to the first day of the current month?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssrs-2012

Using SQL Server: I am trying to find all records prior to the first day of the current month and set this as a parameter in an SSRS report (so I can't use a static value).

So, I need all records prior to the first day of the each current month going forward in column `CREATEDDATETIME` ('yyyy-mm-dd').

I have seen a lot of threads on how to find records for a specific month and various other searches but none specifically related to the above. Interested to see if the `EOMONTH` function will be of use here.

Thanks for the help and advice.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help clarify what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That was my first question on any code forum. I am trying to find the number of employees at each branch location for the previous month. So, when I run the report the next month, I can see only those employees created before the start of that month.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an expression to use [`EOMONTH()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with optional parameter -1.

Explanations:

> DateAdd: add 1 day to expression
>
> getdate is current date
>
> EOMONTH is end day of a given month; however, if you put an optional integer -1, this would mean last month
>
> Thus:  first day of current month is add one day to end of day last month

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(getdate(),-1));

Result: 2018-04-01
```

SO in your query:

```
select * 
from table 
where CREATEDDATETIME < DATEADD(DAY,1,EOMONTH(getdate(),-1));
```

Comment: Sql Server 2012 and later. I wish I had known about this sooner :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `datefromparts()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where CREATEDDATETIME < datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1);
```

Comment: The odds of the two instances of `GetDate()` returning values in differing months (or years) is so small that [Murphy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) is swooning.

Comment: @HABO . . . For whomever you are referring to, `getdate()` is now evaluated once at the beginning of query execution, so the value is constant throughout a query.  This is a "run-time constant" function, similar to `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's already two other answers that work, but for completeness here is a third common technique:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table] 
WHERE CREATEDDATETIME < dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, current_timestamp), 0)
```

You might also get answers suggesting you build the date using strings. Don't do that. It's both the least efficient and most error prone option you could use.

Answer (score 0):

all three answers are great, how ever you may find that it will select all the data prior to the 1st day of the current month until the 1st `Createdate`. This could cause the report to take forever to run, Maybe building in a limitation to the code I would use something like this to build a report that gives details for last month only.

```
Select [columns] 
from [source]
where [Createdate] between
/*First day of last Month*/
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, Getdate())-1, 0 and
/*First day of this Month*/
dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,Getdate()),0)
```